# Selenium OnClick identify button C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

How to identify this button in C#:

```html
 <button class="reward_link_redeem_button_style" onclick="RedeemRPProduct('free_points_1')">REDEEM</button>
 <button class="reward_link_redeem_button_style " onclick="RedeemRPProduct('free_points_50')">REDEEM</button>
```

But there are like 4 buttons called equal, and to differentiate them you need the ('free_points_1') as well as ('free_points_10'), etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using CSS selector

   ```
   .reward_link_redeem_button_style
   ```

   **OR**

   ```
   button[class='reward_link_redeem_button_style']
   ```
2. Using xpath

   ```
   //button[contains(.,'REDEEM')]
   ```

   **OR**

   ```
   //button[contains(@onclick,'RedeemRPProduct')]
   ```

**Update**

As per recent update content. You can locate the element using onclick attribute as it make the element unique. Use below xpath :

```
//button[contains(@onclick,'free_points_50')]
```

Comment: But there are like 4 buttons called equal, and to differentiate them you need the ('free_points_1') as well as ('free_points_10'), etc.

Comment: Can you update the question with some more HTML code so I can help you out

Comment: Try this `//button[contains(@onclick,'free_points_50')]` make sure you have passed correct number

Comment: @GabrielLugo, I have updated the answer as per your update.If this answer is helpful for you then please `accept` so it can be helpful for other. Have some other queries then please post. thanks

Comment: You can still use `CSS` instead of `xpath`: `"button[onclick='RedeemRPProduct('free_points_50')']"`